# Preg_match_all grab value from string

Tags: php, preg-match

Example:

```
$word = "Your IP address=10.0.0.1</br>my ip address=127.0.0.1</br>";
```

how can i taking that ip address string using preg_match_all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pragmatic attempt in this case would be to match everything between the `=` and the `</br>`:

```
preg_match_all('~=(.*?)</br>~', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Note the `?` which marks an ungreedy match. If you omit that you would get the following match:

```
10.0.0.1</br>my ip address=127.0.0.1
```

Of course you need `preg_match_all()` to get every match (IP) an not just the first.

Comment: how can i change the "<\br>" with empty string or space string?

Comment: I don't get you. Can you explain?

Comment: $word = "Your IP address=10.0.0.1 my ip address=127.0.0.1 "; the end of ip address is space string

Comment: Just replace `</br>` by a ` ` (space) then.